# Is it possible to insert a cross-reference within a lstlisting

Tags: cross-referencing

Is there a way to use the \ref{} inside an lstlisting?

Like this:

```
\begin{lstlisting}
  \ref{sec:name}
\end{lstlisting}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out!

You can insert an escape character which lets you use latex code within the lstlisting.

Like this:

```
\begin{lstlisting} [escapechar=@]
  The function specified in Section @\ref{sec:name}@ is used
\end{lstlisting}
```